# HTML Website - Right side getting cut off by background

Tags: html, css

My supervisor at the university asked me to update her website and I found that when I made the browser smaller, a horizontal scroll bar would appear but the right side of the website gets covered with the background. If I open the website on my phone then the right side is just missing. I would at least like to fix the issue with the smaller browser size.

I do not have a lot of html experience; I was only going to update the information. I do not know who wrote the code for the website but would like to fix the issue for my supervisor.

I looked at the code and I do not know what the issue is. I have tried some solutions that were posted on stackoverflow for seemingly similar questions, and nothing has worked.

I am wondering if someone is able to look at the code and potentially identify the issue? This is the website: https://people.trentu.ca/~joannafreeland/index.html

Thank you in advance!

Maria

[image: Code and Screenshot of the issue]

Comment: I do not have the problem you described (Firefox on MacOS) however I do notice the site is not responsive, so its width does not scale with the browser size. I'd look into creating a responsive site and re-work it (if you can/want to).

Comment: @DanielWilliams I have the same issue on IE, Firefox and Chrome on windows. Good to hear that it works on some computers though! I will definitely look into updating it, thank you.

Comment: @Maria You might want to read about CSS grids. It's the easiest responsive website guide to start with. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout

Answer (score 0):

try to put this in the `<head>` of your code :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

**width=device-width**
means, we are telling to the browser “my website adapts to your device width”.
This means that the browser will (probably) render the width of the page at the width of its own screen.

The **initial-scale** property controls the zoom level when the page is first loaded. The maximum-scale, minimum-scale, and user-scalable properties control how users are allowed to zoom the page in or out.

Comment: But the rest of the site is not formatted to be responsive, so this is useless at this point.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not fix the issue. Thank you for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

Or try this:

```
@media screen (max-width:400px) {
}
```

Write this on CSS and between curly brackets you can write a code. The code is actives only, when the screen wide is lower, than 400px.

Answer (score -1):

This won't make your page completely responsive, but maybe you can try adding

```
width: 100%;
```

in the rules under your html, body?

That should help with the cutting off issue. Hope this helps?

EnhancedLoop7